# How to link external excel workbook in office 365 excel online? I linked two sheet, but it is not working for my colleagues?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

In my organization, we have a master tracker (MT.xlsx) maintained by the group manager in his OneDrive folder. Some data from it needs to be shown to other people in the organizations, and hence we have created another tracker (BO.xlsx) which is in my OneDrive folder.

Everytime we have to copy paste the data and this is laborious task. Hence I linked the two sheets using a simple workbook link formula. But this works only when the sheets are open in my laptop and in desktop app and they do not work in Excel browser version.

When my colleagues update MT.xlsx and if both sheets are not open in my laptop, BO.xlsx does not get updated. Can anyone please help me with how can we link the two sheets so that BO.xlsx can be updated without it being open in my laptop?

Comment: Please check this blog is helpful, "[Workbook Link support coming to Excel for the web](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/workbook-link-support-coming-to-excel-for-the-web/ba-p/1590314)".